# What is the preferred way to indent cases in a switch?

Tags: language-agnostic, switch-statement, indentation

As I was writing another switch in Eclipse, I once again came across a rather weird (to me, at least) default indentation, which is applied to 'switch' statements:

```
switch (i) {
case 1:
    ...
case n:
    ...
}
```

I tend to prefer another way:

```
switch (i) {
    case 1:
        ...
    case n:
        ...
}
```

Which way is more readable and eye-pleasing for you? I'm still not hundred percent determined what's best for me, so I'd like to stick to what's best for other people who would read my code.

BTW, you're free to close this question if this is too subjective. :)

Comment: My Eclipse by default indents it as 2nd way. Maybe a missetting in the code formatter of your Eclipse?

Comment: Visual Studio also by default formats in 2nd way.

Comment: @BalusC: Only the "Eclipse 2.1 [built-in]" formatter formats it with extra indentation. Both the "Eclipse [built-in]" and "Java Conventions [built-in]" use no indentation for the case statement (just checked this on Eclipse 3.5).

Comment: Almost every switch statement in a C program that I'm currently working on uses the first example here. I instinctively go to indent them, but then I remember it the first format is used in 5,000 other files :(

Comment: This seems way too subjective.

Comment: Indentation is a fundamental part of coding and doing it consistently is very important for your colleagues, the community and even your future self. How on Earth can this question be considered "not constructive"?

Answer (score 18):

According to the ["official" Java Code Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-142311.html#468), it's the first variant (no additional indentation for case).

Comment: Good that Oracle's (or actually, Sun's) conventions are still archived, but the information was last updated in 1999, so not valid for now. Google's [Java Style Guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html#s4.8.4-switch) does recommend indenting the block contents, though

Comment: So it didn't occur to me until hearing that Oracle recommends the first way. And now I understand why by realizing the grammar is obviously not the same as the typical use of curly braces. For example, a while loop has a grammar of `while ParExpression Statement` whereas a switch is `switch ParExpression { SwitchBlockStatementGroups }`. In the while loop, Statement -> Block: `{ BlockStatements }` which has a different usage and meaning syntactically. This is why I don't like Google so much. They like to just change things up for funsies, and the whole world buys in because it's a big company.

Answer (score 16):

I prefer the second way as well.  But it is more important to stay **consistent** within a particular application and/or within a particular team than it is to indent one way or the other.

Answer (score 14):

I tend to indent all control structure bodies a single (4space) tab like so:

```
switch (i) 
{
    case 1:
        ...
    case n:
        ...
}
```

I consider the switch to be the outer control structure and the case directives part of the body(even though they are part of the control structure).

I would then further tab indent each case like so:

```
switch (i) 
{
    case 1:
        do_something();
    case n:
        do_something_else();
}
```

I find this to be the most readable format for the switch case construct.

As jkohlhepp has mentioned conformity to the code style conventions of the project you are working on is the most important thing, if you are working on a project that has none, it is worth developing some.

Comment: +1 I too place the opening brace on a new line.

Comment: uggg, the open bracket of a block should go on the same line as the block definition.

Comment: -1 since you placed the opening brace on a new line (I'm obviously not downvoting your answer for real, but I really hate that), but +1 (for real this time) for how you indent everything else.

Answer (score 3):

I use second way:

```
switch (i) {
    case 1:
        ...
    case n:
        ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The first method makes logical sense (to me), however I also prefer the second method. I think most of us are conditioned to expect that code inside braces will be indented.

Answer (score 2):

The first is the standard switch case indentation.

```
switch (i) {

case 1:
    .... // Here you can write more code in a row than using the second way
    break;
case n:
    ....
    break;
default:
    ....
    break;
}
```

Notice the new inserted line between switch (i) and case 1:

Comment: I think this (without indentation) is the preferred way in Java, while C# uses the other way (with indentation).