# Eclipse - Formatting Switch Statement

Tags: eclipse, formatting, format, switch-statement

At the moment I have:

```
    switch (numberString) {
       case "FOUR": number = 4; break;
       case "FIVE": number = 5; break;
    }
```

It's a simple switch statement, but if I use Eclipse's format key, <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+F</kbd>, all of a sudden it turns into something 10 lines longer by breaking up case, value =, and break; all on to different lines.

Is there anyway to change the formatter to ignore switch statements?

Answer (score 4):

I'm using Eclipse Oxygen 3a and I found the setting to indent the `case` statements within switch cases:

`Preferences` > `Java` > `Code Style` > `Formatter` > `Edit...` > `Indent`

Check **Statements within 'switch' body**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I've struggled with this too.  The only option seems to be to use the formatter on/off comment tags.

Select the "Off/On Tags" tab in the formatter settings and check "Enable Off/On tags".

Then in your code add `//@formatter:off` before the switch statement and `//@formatter:on` after it.

Pretty sure that's the only workaround for the time being.

Answer (score 1):

Consider (4 years later) **Eclipse 4.12** (2019-06), combined with [**Java 12**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_12) (March 2019).

It now has:

- **[Format whitespaces in 'switch'](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.12/jdt.php#switch-spaces)**

> As Java 12 introduced some new features into the switch construct, the formatter profile has some new settings for it.
>   The settings allow you to control spaces around the arrow operator (separately for case and default) and around commas in a multi-value case.
>
> The settings can be found in the Profile Editor (`Preferences > Java > Code Style > Formatter > Edit...`) under the `White space > Control statements >` '`switch`' subsection.

[image: https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.12/images/formatter-switch.png]

- [**Split Switch Case Labels**](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.12/jdt.php#split-switch-case-labels)

> As Java 12 introduced the ability to group multiple switch case labels into a single case expression, a quick assist is provided that allows these grouped labels to be split into separate case statements.

[image: https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.12/images/split-switch-case-labels.png]

As you can see, those switch expressions remain quite compact.

Comment: Eclipse also has the option `Statements within 'switch' body` that you can check too for the [long standing switch indentation battle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3005797/what-is-the-preferred-way-to-indent-cases-in-a-switch). I've been looking for it for the past few *years*, so ... merci !

Comment: @Matthieu Je vous en prie. Actual thanks to those having implemented that feature.

Comment: I removed my comment, I just found the setting.

Comment: @cbaldan Great: can you edit this answer to include said setting?

Comment: @VonC U just did, I added a new answer.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse's auto format breaks up new lines for every semi colon.  It also will separate long single lines to fit within the view pane with out side to side scrolling - adding the new line with an indent.  Your sample statement seems to be too short to trigger that, but if that is only an example then that's my guess.  I haven't found a way to localize the effect of auto formats. (for mac Cmnd+Shift+F)